# How field values are taken during deserialization in java?

Tags: java, serialization

I tried to understand how de-serialization is done with the example:

```
    class A implements Serializable{
        int x=3;
        long y=4;
        short z=5;
    }

    public class B extends A{
        public B(){
            x=7;
        }

      public String toString(){
          return ""+x+""+y+""+z;
      }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            B b=new B();
    try{
                FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("ser.ser");
                ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                oos.writeObject(b);
                oos.close();
                System.out.println(b);
                FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("ser.ser");
                ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                b=(B)ois.readObject();
                ois.close();
                System.out.println(b);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
}
```

It's produces `745` But when i `implement serializable in B` class the result is `345`

i am not able to understand the difference serialization of of class B is making...

Comment: You're talking about the case when you deserialize right? If yes, then can you add code for serialization, and deserialization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you deserialize an object, then for all the classes up in the hierarchy, which doesn't implement `Serializable` interface, the constructor is invoked to initialize the state in that class.

So, when your class `B` doesn't implement `Serializable`, the constructor runs, and assigns `7` to `x`, and hence you get `745`. However, when it implements `Serializable`, that doesn't happen, and the value for `x` would be the one that it has while the object was serialized, i.e, `3` in this case.

Comment: @AlexR I guessed that he was talking about output after deserialization, as he got `345`. Still I've asked for clarification, let's see. Will update accordingly.

Comment: I do not understand how constructor of class `B` does not run when `new B()` is executed. Please pay attention that class `B` cannot be compiled because something that looks as a constructor is called `Puppy`. I believe that OP tried several versions of his code doing some modifications, then sent here version that cannot be compiled at all, so his question is not relevant....

Comment: @AlexR Oh dear. Didn't notice that.

Comment: @AlexR The constructor *is* called when 'new B()' is executed. Nobody has stated otherwise. It isn't called when a B is *deserialized.* See the Object Serialization Specification.